# Simple way to get extract data from HTML

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, curl, html

After I retrieved a web page with

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/data/123
```

I got this response:

```
<td><a href="http://help.example.com " target="_blank">help.example.com</a></td>
<td><a href="http://hello.example.com " target="_blank">hello.example.com</a></td>
<td><a href="http://test.example.com " target="_blank">test.example.com</a></td>
```

From the above response I want to get all the subdomains,
one by one, with no markup, like:

```
help.example.com
hello.example.com
test.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sed`

```
$ cat test

<td><a href="http://help.domain.com " target="_blank">help.domain.com</a></td>
<td><a href="http://hello.domain.com " target="_blank">hello.domain.com</a></td>
<td><a href="http://test.domain.com " target="_blank">test.domain.com</a></td>

$ sed 's/^.*">//;s/<.*//' test

help.domain.com
hello.domain.com
test.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F'">|</' '{ print $2 }' file
```

Output:

```
help.domain.com
hello.domain.com
test.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `lynx`

```
lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers  http://example.com/data/123 | awk -F'[/:]+' '{print $2}'
```

cat file.html

```
<td><a href="http://help.example.com " target="_blank">help.example.com</a></td>
<td><a href="http://hello.example.com " target="_blank">hello.example.com</a></td>
<td><a href="http://test.example.com " target="_blank">test.example.com</a></td>
```

```
lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers  file.html | awk -F'[/:]+' '{print $2}'
```

Output

```
help.example.com
hello.example.com
test.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time task the other answers are probably alright.

For everything else, use a proper xml or html parser!

E.g.: `BeautifulSoup`:

```bsh
curl -X POST http://example.com/data/123 | python -c '
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
soup=BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin,"lxml")
for a in soup.find_all("a"):
  print(a.string)
'
```

Output:

```
help.example.com
hello.example.com
test.example.com
```

you might need to install `bs4` via `pip`.

Of course you don't need `curl`, when you [request the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python) directly from `python`.